# How to get notification using BLE, always getting Error

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I am trying to get notification from Kotlin on React Native using BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) connection.
Devices are connected each other and I am trying to send notification from Android device to iPhone device.
I am using [react-native-ble-plx](https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx) in React Native and BluetoothGatt in Kotlin.
Service for notification is added exactly, but I am always getting this type of error.

> [BleError: Characteristic 00002b01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb notify change failed for device 7DE9469A-26EA-472F-97D7-16786143626A and service 00002b00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb]

I was not able to find solution during several days of researching by the internet. Below is my React Native side's code.

```js
let service = '00002B00-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB';
    let characteristic = '00002B01-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB';
    const sub = KikiBleManager.bleManager.monitorCharacteristicForDevice(connectedDevice.id, service, characteristic, function (err, result) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err)
    return;
  }
  console.log(result);
});
```